# Unexpected type conversion when looping over a vector of lubridate objects in R

Tags: r, date, for-loop, type-conversion, lubridate

My question is related to [this (closed) lubridate issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/901) but is related to for loops in R more generally:

```r
library(lubridate)
dates=c(ymd("20180501"), ymd("20180502"), ymd("20180503"))
print(dates)
# [1] "2018-05-01" "2018-05-02" "2018-05-03"
# ... as expected

print(dates[1])
# [1] "2018-05-01"
# ... as expected

for(d in dates) print(d)
# [1] 17652
# [1] 17653
# [1] 17654
# ... unexpected!
```

When looping over `dates`, R silently converts the elements of `dates` to numeric, hence losing all their date-ness. This is unexpected and leads to errors, e.g. when printing the date and expecting "2018-05-01", but getting an integer instead.

The reply of the lubridate dev in the github issue is

> `in` operator in `for (x in dates)` is "primitive" and doesn't decompose the date-time vector into date-times. So x is surprisingly "numeric".

They suggest to use `purrr::map` or `for (i in seq_along(dates))` instead. Sure in the example above `map(dates, print)` is more concise and probably preferable, but there are cases where someone might prefer to use a for loop to iterate over a vector of dates.

I wonder where and how errors related to this behavior should be caught:

1. As a user how can I best catch the unexpected conversion from date to numeric in a for loop here? Should I get into the habit of always using `for (i in seq_along(dates)) d = dates[i] ...`?
2. In general, when do I have to be careful about `for ... in` silently converting my data?
3. Is that something the lubridate developers could handle more gracefully, i.e. by throwing a warning?
4. This is quite far-fetched, but: Is there something the R developers could address here by fixing the `in` operator?

Comment: Conversion of date class to numeric occurs not only in `for` loop.  It can happen in `unlist`ing.  I guess you already know the answer to this issue.

Comment: Q1: don't `for` over the `dates`, iterate over the indices; Q2: it depends on the data; Q3: no, it's a base R thing; Q4: this is the same as 3.

Comment: @akrun Thanks, but no I'm afraid I don't know the answer.

Comment: I meant that you already provided `for(i in seq_along(dates))` which would be the best option.  In `R`, the for loops are for each and not the traditional for loops you find in other languages

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @akrun. There seems to be a gap in my R knowledge here that I'd like to close. Any suggestions where I could read up on what you mean by "for loops in R are for each and not traditional for loops"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend that you do this, but you can change for loops to fix this (at least in your own code).

Like just about every other operation in R, `for` loops are implemented as a function.  In this case `for` is a reserved word, so you need to use backticks to refer to it, but you could define your own function to replace the standard one.

For example:

```r
`for` <- function(var, seq, expr ) {
  # We want to use the original within this fn:
  `for` <- base::`for`
  
  # Get the working variable
  var <- deparse(substitute(var))
  
  # Loop over the sequence
  for (i in seq_along(seq)) {
    assign(var, seq[[i]], envir = parent.frame())
    eval(substitute(expr), envir = parent.frame())
  }
  invisible(NULL)
}

library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
dates=c(ymd("20180501"), ymd("20180502"), ymd("20180503"))

for(d in dates) print(d)
#> [1] "2018-05-01"
#> [1] "2018-05-02"
#> [1] "2018-05-03"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I don't guarantee that I got the environments right here, so use at your own risk!

Regarding your questions:

Q1:  I don't think there's any obvious way to do that.  Just avoid `for (a in b)`, and stick with `for (i in seq_along(b))` unless you know what `b` is, e.g. because you just created it.  But if a user sent it to you, don't trust `for (a in b)`.

Q2:  You need to worry about this whenever `unclass(seq)[i]` gives a different value than `seq[i]`, because `for` (mostly?) ignores the class.

Q3:  I don't think `lubridate` could reasonably detect this other than by replacing the `for` loop like I did, but that would have such a negative effect on efficiency, I hope they never would.  It might be against the CRAN rules to do that; if not, CRAN would probably add a new rule.

Q4:  There is no `in` operator.  It's just part of the syntax of the `for` loop, like the parentheses.  But they could fix the `for` loop to use `seq[i]` instead of internally accessing the values, i.e. no longer ignore the class of the object.  But this would be hugely slower than the current implementation, so I doubt if they'd do it, especially given the workaround of using `for (i in seq_along(seq))` that is available to you if you want fancy indexing.

EDITED to add:

I just did a bit of comparison of timing, and the substituted `for` loop is slower, but not actually a huge amount slower than the standard one.  So maybe R Core would consider a change.

Comment: The answers are great. upvoted and accepted. I hope you don't mind me moving the cool but dirty hack of the for function (which you do not recommend  anyway) to the bottom. Feel free to undo the change.

Comment: I have rolled back the change, which I think changed the intention of my answer.